# Setting up similar weblements using a list<webelement> in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've several page elements / records having xpath / id's like this

```
//*[@id='xyz-model-car-card-0']/car
//*[@id='xyz-model-car-card-1']/car
//*[@id='xyz-model-car-card-2']/car
```

and i am looking to add these webelements using List so that i can take any action on them.

```
List<WebElement> item = Arrays.asList();
// incase i want to navigate to 5 cards..
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
item.add(By.id('xyz-model-car-card-'+i));
}
```

but, i am unable to add it.. giving below error..

```
*add (org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)
in List cannot be applied to (org.openqa.selenium.By)*
```

Whats the best way to deal with such webelements name if we want to load them in one go.`enter code here`

Pl. share some example.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a webdriver named 'driver':

```
List<WebElement> xyzModels = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id='xyz-model-car-card-')]/car));

For (WebElement car : xyzModels) {
    //your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add the By object to your WebElement list:

```
item.add(By.id('xyz-model-car-card-'+i));
```

You need to add the web element instead (assuming you are using driver when you instantiate your new browser object):

```
item.add(driver.findElement(By.id('xyz-model-car-card-'+i)));
```

But, I agree with Bill Hileman's answer.  Best way to add the elements to a list is to do this:

```
List<WebElement> myList = driver.findElements(By.....)
```